# Table expands beyond body (html)

Tags: html, css

So what is happening is that my table has expanded over my body, even though it is contained within it, I think screenshots is the best way to show this of when I have over the elements when I'm inspecting them (Chrome):

**Body**

[image]

**tableData (wrapper for table)**

[image]

**Table**

[image]

This is my code:

```
<body>
  <main>
      <div class="tableData">
          <table>
              "..."
          </table>
      </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

I need my **body** to completely contain the **table** for styling purposes. How would be the best way to go about this? Is there a CSS overflow property I need to set?

Comment: And also try to add overflow: auto; to table.

Comment: Tried adding that both to the wrapper and the table itself: no difference but takes a longer time to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser probably decides it cannot possibly fit your table within its container and instead lets it overflow. If that is the case, you could set `overflow-x: auto` on `.tableData` to add horizontal scrollbars to the wrapper, technically making the table fit inside the body.

You can of course always investigate why the table is so wide. It may be because of cell padding, `white-space: nowrap` somewhere or other things that forces it to be unnecessarily wide.

Another possible cause, which would explain why scrollbars won't appear on the wrapper, would be if the table has `position: absolute` (or `fixed`), taking it out of the normal layout flow.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` seems to have offered a nice alternative. My table no stays visible with the wrapper have an x scrollbar (as I added `overflow-x: auto` as well). Thank you!